# maybe crazy question on asymptotic notation

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computer-science

I see two time complexity.

$O ( m (\log m + \log n))$ and $O(m \log m \log n)$.

> Is it correct that according to logarithm rules tell these are equals A) from asymptotic view and B) from math point of view,
> to each other or I'm in a big mistake forever.

Comment: Rules of logarithms say $\log m + \log n = \log (mn)$, not $\log m + \log n = (\log m)(\log n)$.

Comment: @RiversMcForge so can we say mlog m+ mlog n ?

Answer (score 0):

Dont know exactly what you are asking for but I think the following is true:

Consider $f(x)=O\bigl(m(\log m+\log n)\bigr)$. Assuming that this is not some multivariable function with respect to $m$ and $n$ and instead that, for instance $m=K$ where $K$ is some constant. Then we have that $$f(x)=O\bigl(\underbrace{K\cdot \log K}_\text{const. C=O(1)}+K\cdot \log n)\bigr)=O\bigl(O(1)+K\cdot \log n)\bigr)=O(K\cdot \log n)=O(\log n)$$ $\forall n>n_{0}$. That is $$O\bigl(K\log K+K\log n)\bigr)=O(\log n).$$